# libAdIdAccess.a location?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Following the instructions to use IDFA with Google Analytics on iOS (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features), I must link `libAdIdAccess.a` to my app. I'm using CocoaPods with the latest Analytics SDK and I can't find this file in the Pods folder.

After some research, I downloaded the SDK directly from Google and there it is. Is there a way to get this file from CocoaPods?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should install another pod called **GoogleIDFASupport** using CocoaPods.

Please refer to my attachment and links below:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleIDFASupport

https://developers.google.com/ios/cocoapods

[image]