# Firebase - linking to libAdIdAccess.a

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I use `Firebase Analytics` in my project. I have installed it with `CocoaPods`. I'd like to have access to all automatically collected user properties like it is described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484). It says there:

> For iOS apps, the app must collect IDFA in order to automatically derive the Age, Gender, and Interests properties.

In order to do that I should link to the following libraries:

- libAdIdAccess.a
- AdSupport.framework

This is described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039). I know how to link the `AdSupport.framework`.
But where should I find `libAdIdAccess.a`. This has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165164/libadidaccess-a-location). The answer suggests to install the pod `GoogleIDFASupport`. I already did that but wonder if it's the correct action since it's not mentioned in the `Firebase` documentation, only in the `Google Analytics` one. And in `Google Analytics` it's not enough to install the pod, you should also:

> To enable IDFA collection, set the allowIDFACollection property to YES on each tracker that will collect the IDFA. For example:
>
> // Enable IDFA collection.
>   tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;

The question is: Is it enough to use the pod `GoogleIDFASupport` or should I acquire `libAdIdAccess.a` another way?

Comment: Yes in my production code I am using the pod GoogleIDFASupport and everything is working as expected.

Comment: @GeorgiBoyadzhiev Great, thanks for your reply. Just to make sure - you are using it with Firebase, right?

Comment: I was using it with Google Analytics too and later migrated to Firebase. I am not entirely familiar with all the ways to use it, however I can confirm for the Firebase synergy.

Comment: hi @surToTheW, I got the same issue. Did you use 'pod GoogleIDFASupport'? it's OK?